# window.parent.postMessage and window.location.hostname for the targetDomain

Tags: javascript, iframe, dom-events

In a child iframe I'm using `window.parent.postMessage('some msg', targetDomain)` to message out to the parent. Originally, the targetDomain was a hard-coded 'string' (e.g., `http://my.childdomain.com`). I've since been asked - for reasons we'll pass over here - to instead plan for the targetDomain to be dynamic. I then tried targetDomain as `http://'+window.location.hostname` but something isn't right.

I've `alert(window.location.hostname)` just prior and get the right value but `window.parent.postMessage()` doesn't seem to like `window.location.hostname`.

Any suggesions?

Answer (score 0):

Opps. Problem solved. The primary issue was I wasn't parsing the window.location.hostname to get the TLD. Once I got some sleep and came to my senses I realized the error of my ways. That is, I needed to tell window.parent.postMessage where the msg is going, not where it's coming from. Yeah, I know...duh??